# iOS Scale UIWindow ,but the statusBar can not scale?

Tags: ios

As you can see,The first pic is what effect i want.but the i just can make effect like pic 2.the statusBar can not scale with UIWindow.
what can i do? who can give me some tips!

1. **What i want:**

   [image]
2. **What i made:**

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, `UIStatusBar` is not a part of any `UIWindow`, so you scale an `UIWindow` take no effect on `UIStatusBar`.

You can use `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` API to take a screenshot image, and show the image in `UIImageView`, than you can scale the `UIImageView` rather than the `UIWindow`.